# Not receiving query results from database after search form submitted

Tags: php, mysql

I have two files, `file.php` amd `get_xml.php`. I can, without a problem echo table information in both php files, but when I want to use a search form to query data, send it off to `get_xml.php`, I get no results.

[Here is a working example along with all rows as a reference as to what is in the actual MySQL table.](http://nightlifebratislava.com/mysqlmap/file.php)

Now here's the code itself:

**file.php**

```
<?php
$username="****";
$password="*******";
$database="******";

mysql_connect(localhost,$username,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");
$query="SELECT * FROM markers";
$result=mysql_query($query);

$num=mysql_num_rows($result);

mysql_close();
?>


<form action="get_xml2.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
Address: <input type="text" name="address"><br>
Type: <input type="text" name="type"><br>
<input type="Submit">
</form>
```

**get_xml2.php**

```
<?php
require("db_access.php");

function parseToXML($htmlStr) 
{ 
$xmlStr=str_replace('<','&lt;',$htmlStr); 
$xmlStr=str_replace('>','&gt;',$xmlStr); 
$xmlStr=str_replace('"','&quot;',$xmlStr); 
$xmlStr=str_replace("'",'&#39;',$xmlStr); 
$xmlStr=str_replace("&",'&amp;',$xmlStr); 
return $xmlStr; 
} 

$name=$_POST['name'];
$address=$_POST['address'];
$type=$_POST['type'];


// Opens a connection to a MySQL server
$connection=mysql_connect (localhost, $username, $password);
if (!$connection) {
  die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
}

// Set the active MySQL database
$db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $connection);
if (!$db_selected) {
  die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysql_error());
}




// Select all the rows in the markers table
$query = sprintf(
   "SELECT name, address, type FROM markers WHERE name = '%s' AND address = '%s' AND     type = '%s'",
   mysql_real_escape_string($name),
   mysql_real_escape_string($address),
   mysql_real_escape_string($type)
);
$result = mysql_query($result);
if($result == false) {
   die(mysql_error() . "<br />\n$query");
}
if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
   user_error("No rows returned by:<br />\n$query");
} 

header("Content-type: text/xml");

// Start XML file, echo parent node
echo '<markers>';

// Iterate through the rows, printing XML nodes for each
while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  // ADD TO XML DOCUMENT NODE
  echo '<marker ';
  echo 'name="' . parseToXML($row['name']) . '" ';
  echo 'address="' . parseToXML($row['address']) . '" ';
  echo 'type="' . parseToXML($row['type']) . '" ';
  echo 'lat="' . $row['lat'] . '" ';
  echo 'lng="' . $row['lng'] . '" ';
  echo '/>';
}

// End XML file
echo '</markers>';

?>
```

When you do a search, as you can see you will get this:

```
> Query was empty
SELECT name, address, type 
FROM markers 
WHERE name = 'The Melting Pot' 
AND address = '14 Mercer St, Seattle, WA' 
AND type = 'restaurant'
```

However, when I change the code in the xml to

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM markers WHERE 1";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
  die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

[The xml happily retrieves ALL data in from the database, as seen here](http://nightlifebratislava.com/mysqlmap/get_xml.php).

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll probably kick yourself for this.

```
$result = mysql_query($result);
```

Should be

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

Don't ya hate that? :-)

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH, however can you help me with one more thing? The xml now returns results only if I fill in ALL of the fields correctly. Can I modify the script so that it returns the corresponding row if I, for example fill out TYPE, or NAME? Thanks :)

Comment: So you want to conditionally add a where clause?  Simply put conditional statements and checks around the SQl.  i.e. if(empty($name)){$nameClause=''}else{$nameClause="name='".$name."'"} then put $nameClause in where you have $name in the sql statement.  That way the condition checking is only in place when the variable has something.

Comment: hmmmm I tried this if (empty($name)) {
  $nameClause='';
} else {
  $nameClause="name='".$name."'";
} but it still required me to fill out all fields even when I did this: mysql_real_escape_string($nameClause). I would bother you more but it's difficult to communicate in this textbox so I'll just file it under a new question. Thanks again :)!

Answer (score 3):

you have a mistake:

```
$result = mysql_query($result);
```

instead of

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
```